# How to uninstall software which install through config, make, make install on Mac

Tags: mac, uninstall, mutt

I want to uninstall mutt which I installed in the following way.

```
$ cd mutt-1.5.21
$ patch -p1 < ../patch-1.5.21.sidebar.txt
$ ./configure   
$ make
$ make install
```

Answer (score 1):

If your makefile supports it, `make uninstall` would be the easiest.  Otherwise, you can simulate the install process with `make -n install` which will show you what was actually done by the install command (but, not doing it again).